# Loop through angular js array in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-factory

I have a web api that returns `List<KeyValuePair<string, byte>>` to an angular js factory. I then present it in an select using ->

```
<select ng-model="survey.surveyType" class="form-control" id="surveyType">
                    <option ng-repeat="surveyType in surveyTypes" value="{{surveyType.value}}">{{surveyType.key}}</option>
                </select>
```

This works fine. Angular loops and displays the object correctly. When talking to the web api method I have configured it like this ->

```
app.factory('Survey', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
return $resource('http://localhost:52133/api/surveyapi/:id', null,
    {
        'update': { method: 'PUT' },
        'getSurveyTypesAsDictionary': { method: 'GET', isArray: true, url: 'http://localhost:52133/api/surveyapi/GetSurveyTypesAsDictionary' }
    });
}]);

// fetching the values in my controller
var surveyTypes = Survey.getSurveyTypesAsDictionary();
```

Now my problem is this. I can't loop the result. In the console the object looks like this ->

[image]

But if I try to get the values inside my angular array there's nothing there. For instance `surveyTypes.length` is 0.

Question. How can I consume the array using JavaScript?
Thanks!

EDIT:
I tried to return only `Dictionary<string, byte>` from the web api but I didn't get it to work at all.

EDIT, comment to Sergiu:

```
var promise = Survey.getSurveyTypesAsDictionary();
promise.$promise.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.length);
});
```

to make your suggestion work I have to get `$promise` from the object. Is this correct or do I need to configure my factory to make it work the way your syntax is written?

Comment: `getSurveyTypesAsDictionary` makes an _asynchronous_ request and returns a _promise_. You need to use `Survey.getSurveyTypesAsDictionary().then(function(response) { // response can be used here });`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Thanks Sergiu, made a follow up question in the edit :)

Comment: Yes, you can use the raw `$promise` object like that or you can use the _callback_ syntax as described in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Answer (score 4):

First off, the returned `resource object` has action methods which provide high-level behaviors without the need to interact with the low level `$http` service.

For example

```
Post.query(function(data) {
    $scope.posts = data;
});
```

or, you can also access the raw `$http` promise via the `$promise` property on the object returned

```
 var req = Post.query().$promise;
 req.then(function(data) { 
     $scope.posts = data;
 });
```